# How to call another API and return data with pagination?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a controller which making another api call and loop through the results, create custom object and return the result.

What is the best way to add pagination and filter on that?
Before I do it manually, I think there got to be a way to do it with Sails framework.

My current controller codes are:

```
request.get({
  url: 'https://api.nytime.com/v1/articles?apiKey=xxxx&source=Client1'
}, function(error, response, body) {

  if (error) {
    sails.log.error(error);
  }
  else {
    var asd = JSON.parse(body);
    if (asd.status == 'error') {
        sails.log.error(asd.message);
        return res.send(asd);
        return false;
      }
    var newRtnStr = new Array();
    var b = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < asd.articles.length; i++) { 
        b = {
            "title": "" + asd.articles[i]["title"],
            "source": "" + asd.articles[i]["author"],
            "description": "" + asd.articles[i]["description"],
            "link": "" + asd.articles[i]["url"],
            "category": "NYTimes",
            "media": asd.articles[i]["urlToImage"],
            "rssdate": "" + asd.articles[i]["IL.pubdate"],
            "id": "" + i,
            "createdAt": "" + asd.articles[i]["publishedAt"],
            "updatedAt": "" + asd.articles[i]["publishedAt"]
        }
        newRtnStr.push(b);
    }
    return res.send(newRtnStr);
```

What I think that I am not using the Model here, its just controller which is being called from my routes.

I followed the tutorial describing how to use blueprints and service to filter and create pagination, but I am not sure how do I use that, since my Model is empty here.

Once I have find.js under blueprints folder and ActionUtilityService.js under services folder, the tutorial says call the following.

```
const Pagination = require('sails-pagination')
const buildParams = Pagination.build(q.query)
PublicNews
    .find(buildParams)
    .then((models) => {
      return [
        models,
            PublicNews.count(buildParams)
      ]
    })
```

In my case "PublicNews" is my model, but it is empty. Based on the codes above, my custom object that has data, and need the filter and pagination, is called "newRtnStr".

Comment: Have you already checked if this plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-pagination) can be useful to you?

Comment: You can't do the pagination on client side with something like angularjs?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I can't use the client side paging since I am building and API, so pagination and filter has to be done on server end.

I modify the question above and showed what challenge I am facing using sails-pagination.

Comment: The pagination available in sails is definitely intended for your own db that you manage through a Model. None of the out-of-the-box stuff will work (`.sort`, `.limit`, `.skip`, etc) if it's not from your own db.

Comment: The right thing to do is likely to let the api you are using handle the paging if it can. There is likely a way to handle how many records you want, how to sort, how many to skip, etc in the api. If they don't provide that, they you are left with doing that work in your controller. Can you tell us what sort of records you are fetching? Would it be worth creating your own mirrored records in your own db?

Comment: @arbuthnott Thank you. This is exactly what I am trying to do.
I need to assign my object value to the Model so I can use .sort .limit etc. I don't want to mirror all of these records into my table just because it will be redundent data, and I can't track on the updates on both ends.  Rightnow my Model value is empty, so what I am trying to do is that somehow once the values fetched in the controller, use the .sort .limit etc that is available

Comment: @ShyBoy I'm afraid that won't work - the implementations of .sort, .limit etc all work only in a database. You could probably find an npm module that does paging for you when you have data in memory (like in a variable returned from an api call). But you should really check if the api call already does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Embrace [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).  The NY Times API  gives you a way to indicate to them paging parameters (page, always 10 per).

I would simply pass that information from the client to them through querystring params or similar.  I would also give the client only the next and previous results links and enough information for them to figure the rest out themselves.  The only real problem is that they don't tell you how many pages there are, so that limits what you can do with pagination.  You might try pre-fetching the next page, just to makes sure there is one, or not.

For example, your return object I would change into an object and apply metadata to it:

```
var newRtnStr = { 
   meta: {
      current: "https://example.com/articles?page=3", // URL to the current query results
      next: "https://example.com/articles?page=4",
      previous: "https://example.com/articles?page=2"
    },
    articles: []
};
var b = {};
for (var i = 0; i < asd.articles.length; i++) { 
    b = {
        "title": "" + asd.articles[i]["title"],
        "source": "" + asd.articles[i]["author"],
        "description": "" + asd.articles[i]["description"],
        "link": "" + asd.articles[i]["url"],
        "category": "NYTimes",
        "media": asd.articles[i]["urlToImage"],
        "rssdate": "" + asd.articles[i]["IL.pubdate"],
        "id": "" + i,
        "createdAt": "" + asd.articles[i]["publishedAt"],
        "updatedAt": "" + asd.articles[i]["publishedAt"]
    }
    newRtnStr.articles.push(b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. The NYtime is just a sample filler, I am making a call to another server that provide 100 feeds per call, so that why I am looking for a solution that allows me to filter and page based on my customer object that is created. which is newRtnStr.

Comment: also I am not sure that is this the right way I am doing it or not.

Comment: I've followed the following article for implementing the paging.
https://hellosails.com/how-to-implement-url-pagination-for-sails-js-api/
But the newly added service is not being called, do I have to do something to invoke the service?
In my case my model is empty but my controller does have above codes to call another API, retrive data and then return it, when I use the codes on this article to see if pagination works, it completely ignored. Do I have to do something to invoke the service?

Comment: Sails has nothing to do with it. You need to figure out how the service you're calling hamdles paging and then proxy that.